# Android emulator not showing html5 canvas in webview

Tags: android, webview, html5-canvas, titanium

Since a couple of days the Android emulators don't show html5 canvas drawings in the webview. I have tried to load both local and remote files (like http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html), but without success. Everything else works though (css, javascript, html). Anyone else experiences similar issues?

Comment: you've tagged Titanium, how is it related?

Comment: I tagged it with Titanium, because it happens on a Titanium project. But I don't know if it's a Titanium issue or an Android issue.

Comment: Yes, I have just hit this issue.  Did you find a solution or a cause?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jdias/ztpBF/ works in a webview though.  Strange

Comment: No I did not find a solution yet. When I want to test canvas things, I just test it on real devices.

Comment: For me it works with Android 9 in the emulator, but not with Android 8.x

Comment: I tried adding a border to the canvas, e.g. "border: 1px solid black" and it became visible.  However, any pixels drawn on the canvas did not show up, but you could see it if it had a background color.
Tested on Android 7 emulator

Answer (score 0):

have you enable Javascript? by default its not enable for security purpose,
for android-studio project try

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

hope it may help